# MonthCalendar Display

Tags: c#, .net

I have a MonthCalendar, windows forms, that is shown when I click a button. The problem is that I want to show the month calendar in the right side of the form, but it is not shown correctly, because part of it is outside the form. How can I show it correctly without moving the month calendar?

Comment: ... and some screenshots, so that we know exactly what your problem is ..

Comment: Try changing the parent window of the calendar

Comment: This link may help you:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280891/make-user-control-display-outside-of-form-boundry

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses! The problem was that part of the control wasn't shown correctly because of its position. I figured out that I can fix it if I check the distance between the button and the right, left, top and bottom of the form. If the distance is more than the monthcalendar width - draw it as usual, if it is less - draw it different way :)